# How can I make my button(hyperlink) accessible without a mouse? (FF)

Tags: html, css, accessibility

**THIS IS A FIREFOX ISSUE**

I have a button with both tabindex and accesslink attributes on the hyperlink but I am still not able to tab to the button.

```
<a class="ENVnextButton nextBackBtn rightBtn buttonBig"  href="slide-02.html" id="beginCourse" accesskey="1" tabindex="1">Begin Course</a>
```

Here is the modal I am building.

http://corfro.com/modal/

I am using the jQuery UI Modal to pull in this page:
http://corfro.com/modal/test-layout.html

How can I make this button accessible without a mouse?

*using FF on OS*

Comment: Works on Chrome on OSX for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "accessible"? It's possible to tab to it for me. Are you looking for some kind of keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I just want to be able to hit tab and get to the button so I can hit enter and it will take me to the next page. I don't need a keyboard shortcut but tried accesskey anyway.

Comment: Looks like it works on chrome. Maybe it's a FireFox Issue.

Comment: Updated issue to include firefox browser only

Comment: take out the accesskey and tabindex, and should be fine.

Comment: Where's the doctype? I'd say please validate then debug other things BUT it appears to be valid according to "HTML5 Conformance Checker". How is this even remotely valid to have meta and title in body (and also in head)? Then why are there so many tabindex attributes in HTML source code? This should be applied in JS by your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome JavaScript plugin called [Mousetrap](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) that will let you assign behaviors to custom keyboard shortcuts. Try binding the mousetrap event to the click event of your anchor.